# ionic problem No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm working on an ionic apps.
My problem is: when I try to get data from server I got this:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://mywebsite.com/api. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

I already try to add this to .htaccess:

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
</ifModule>
```

And this to my api page (PHP): `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');`

but still not working

$http.get(url).success(function(response) {...}

Comment: If you are not getting data while running this on browser you need to add Extension named Allow Control Allow Origin

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Put it on top of your PHP file like:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
// then your stuff goes here

?>
```

Note: as with all uses of the PHP header function, this must be before any output has been sent from the server.

Comment: still not working.
all my php file start with header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

Comment: Could you post your API full URL pls?

Comment: thank you i found the probleme it was the url 
a canged domaine.com by www.domaine.com and it work

Answer (score 11):

This cors problem has a simple work around in ionic.

Go to your ionic.config.json (previously ionic.project) and add a proxy for example:

```
{
  "name": "proxy-example",
  "app_id": "",
  "proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/api",
      "proxyUrl": "http://cors.api.com/api"
    }
  ]
}
```

After that use "/api/" instead of "https://mywebsite.com/api" when you call your api.

For more info:

http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/

Comment: A proxy is not needed when not using ionic serve. You need to use the actual URL.

Comment: This is only usable when you are using the ionic serve server. When you deploy to the device, it does not work. The correct answer is to properly implement CORS on your server.

Comment: Ionic apps dont require cors on the device, they are not chrome.

Comment: I tried to do this but now I get 404 (Not Found) error. Do I need to do something else?

Comment: @WesinAlves Look at your console and see what the proxy is to. Maybe you've missed something in the routing

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical error found when we work with Angular and Ionic, the problem appears because when your app loaded in a browser on your app loads all the content from an **origin** that comes from your local address `http://localhost:8100`, then when you want to make any AJAX request sent out to another host than  `localhost:8100`  the request  is called from an any point different from the **origin** its require a **CORS**(Cross Origin Resource Sharing) preflight request to see if it can access the resource.

The solution is use a Proxy To Backend, with this you can highjack certain urls and send them to a backend server. The implementation is easy:

1.- Modify the file `ionic.config.json` in the root folder of your project.

2.- Configure your proxy, inside your `ionic.config.json` file put this, assuming your new host is in `http://localhost:3000`.

```js
   "proxies": [
{
  "path": "/endpoints",
  "proxyUrl": "http://localhost:3000"
}
  ]
```

3.- In your Service change a little the path of your request from this `http://localhost:3000/endpoints/any/path/that/you/use` to this `../endpoints/any/path/that/you/use`(assuming the another host is in `localhost:3000` and the context is `/endpoints`)

If you need more  information about this please check http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/

Answer (score 1):

premise: This issue is usually only running ionic serve, or using ionic as web app, not in ionic as app.

You can avoid to modify your project and use an extension to disable CORS:

For developing with chrome, something like this:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi/related

or, if you need it for firefox, something like this:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cors-everywhere/

IE and Edge sucks so for these you have to manually disable CORS in settings