# Cross Domain error in ionic 2

Tags: api, ionic2, cross-domain

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
  
})
export class HomePage {
posts:any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public http: Http) {
   
   this.navCtrl=navCtrl;
   
   
   this.http.get('API link').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(
    response => {
        this.posts = response.data.resource;
  console.log(this.posts);
    },
    err => {
        console.log("Oops!");
    });
 
 
 }
 
    show(){
 this.navCtrl.push(Nextpage,{
      param1: 'Recent Activities'});
 }
  }
```

i am new to ionic 2, getting cross domain error while requesting API using GET method, how do i allow cross domain: true in ionic 2.attached the error screen shot. Please suggest.

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38359981/2490286

Comment: Now able to get the data but unable to display the images on html file as the image is having dropbox link in Rest API, so when i am fetching it on html this is showing link like  GET http://localhost:8100/dl.dropbox.com/s/6y3d9tkbvbtd4qi/Pensive%20Parakeet.jpg?dl=0 404 (Not Found).  Problem is localhost. I am retrieving in html file with the tag: <img src="{{post.URL}}" /> ,Please suggest me how to get rid of this error.

Comment: Your url is slightly wrong. Add an http://dl.dropbox.com............ otherwise it automatically adds host address at the begnining

Comment: In API dropbox link is dl.dropbox.com/s/6y3d9tkbvbtd4qi/…it automatically adding host address, dont know how..??