# Cannot access API on Xcode app (Ionic) installed on iPhone

Tags: xcode, ionic-framework, ionic3

I managed to install my Ionic application on my iPhone through Xcode. The application is working correctly, except on the part when I am supposed to access an API of my creation. When I press the button that calls the API (I'm inspecting the console through Safari), I get an error. Three errors in fact.

```
[Error] Origin http://localhost:8080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
[Error] Failed to load resource: Origin http://localhost:8080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. (username, line 0)
[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://myapi.com/username due to access control checks.
```

Any insight on this will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand it myself. The API I'm using is in a server, but it's like the iPhone itself is running on localhost:8080 and I don't understand why. The application is installed on the iPhone so I don't get it. I should say this is my first time doing this. Also I installed the application on an Android phone and I didn't have this problem.

Comment: Probably duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38357699/ionic-probleme-no-access-control-allow-origin?rq=1 see if that helps

Comment: Search CORS [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/wkwebview/).